# Extract ang join from same column in Hive

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have a requirement to have different data from single column from another table.

Lets say I have a TAB_A with below sets of columns.
[image]

TAB_B has one column.

[image]

My expected out put should be,
[image]

Here col_x should have the data when code(TAB_B) = '08'
and
col_y should have the data when code(TAB_B) = '36'.

Whatever I have tried is not working,

```
SELECT 
a.col1, 
a.col2, 
a.col3, 
a.col4, 
substr(a.col5,13,3) as col_x,
substr(a.col5,13,3) as col_y
from TAB_A a 
JOIN TAB_B b on b.code = '08'
JOIN TAB_B b on b.code = '36'
```

Can anyone please suggest the best solution.

Comment: could you show some sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

You requirement is not pretty clear but seems you are looking for **cross join** and **case when** clause

```
SELECT 
a.col1, 
a.col2, 
a.col3, 
a.col4, 
case when code(TAB_B) = '08' then substr(a.col5,13,3)  else null end as col_x,
case when  code(TAB_B) = '36'then substr(a.col5,13,3)  else null end as col_y,
from TAB_A a 
JOIN TAB_B
```

;